# Is it possible to use bpython in Sublime Text?

Tags: python, sublimetext, bpython

I have bpython installed, and it's working perfectly when I call it on my terminal. But I use Sublime Text to write my Python, and I would like to have bpython on it.

Has anyone succeeded to integrate it in Sublime?
Or is there another way to get the same help that bpython offers?
Thank you in advance for your help ;)

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no bpython integration for Sublime Text. But if you want interactive Python development in Sublime, you can use [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL). Documentation can be found [here](https://sublimerepl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you soooo much ! You save me from big headache ! Love from China !

Comment: You could acept the answer and help a guy out :)